# How much space do the data of apps take on the phone storage?

Tags: app2sd, internal-storage

As I am seriously out of space on my phone storage on my HTC Desire, I would like an overview of how much phone storage each app takes up. The point is that I can see how much space the data of each app takes up, but not where this data is placed, hence I cannot conclude how much space each app is taking up on the phone storage.

Comment: Your question is very close to this one: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/what-can-i-do-to-manage-my-phones-internal-storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Disk Usage application](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) can show you all this information in a nice graphical format, allowing you to explore the space taken up by applications in your phone memory, or the space taken up by files on your SD card.

[App2SD](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd) will also display information for all apps, although it doesn't split the space into segments based on app/data/cache like Disk Usage does. However, it will allow you to move all apps that you can to the SD card from the phone memory, and provides an easy way to see all the apps installed on the phone, and one click access to the main application settings to uninstall applications.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure that the space shown for each app is the space used on the phone storage, and does not include space used on the SD card.  You can verify this by checking an app in `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications`, then unmount and remove the SD card and check again.