# what is my personal data storage as opposed to program storage  and how can I reduce it?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-tab, internal-storage, storage

I am using Android 2.2, samsung galaxy tablet.
When I look at task manager, summary it list 4 types of storage
1. program    mine is 1.1 / 1.5 gb full
2. personal data      59.35 / 81.26 megabytes
3. internal sd storage 10 / 12.8 gb
3. external sd storage 13.7 / 14.83 gb

It is 2. personal data that is giving me trouble. For many weeks it was over 70 Mb / 81.26 mb and I was getting warnings about my database storage being nearly full. At times the phone would slow down or crash, mp3s would not play smoothly and SMS couldn't be received. Clearing phone logs and texts and programs I didn't use much etc only helped for a very short while.

When I look at main menu, applications,  manage applications, running - 
it says my calendar storage is 180 kb
contacts storage  0.98 MB
maps 10.49 mb
facebook 5.7 mb
yahoo mail 4 mb   Are these figures relevant?
The big one in this list is 
media storage 53.0 mb   (I have much more than that in my internal SD storage in many small files, but deleting 4000 of them didn't change my personal data storage even after a reboot).

For the last few days my personal data storage has stayed just under 60 mb and is not giving problems,  but I'm not sure what is different this week and What does the personal data storage consist of and where is/was the main part of my problem coming from?
I also note that when I reboot the phone the media scanner runs and takes forever and slows the phone.  This last week I have just noticed that when it is nearly finished my personal data storage jumps to over 70 and I get warnings again. But it goes back to about 59/81 after a few minutes.
Is the amount of personal data storage I am using higher than usual ?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/what-can-i-do-to-manage-my-phones-internal-storage

Answer (score 1):

Program storage is the amount of space taken up by the actual app, i.e. the APK size, personal data storage is the space taken up by your personal data. I.e. if you have a to-do list program it would likely create a database and all the to-do are added to the database which would take up personal data storage space.

The only way to reduce personal data storage is to clear the app data, but this will delete all your personal data for the app, i.e. settings and based on the example above all of your to-do's.

What I tend to do is go to settings > applications > manage applications and then go to the all tab. Then on the menu go to sort by size and clear some of the apps near the top that take the most amount of size that aren't a big deal if I lose the data. Google Maps is usually one that takes a lot of personal data storage space.

Hope this helps