# HTC STATUS-INTERNAL MEMORY LOW EVEN WITH SD-CARD?

Tags: internal-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/what-can-i-do-to-manage-my-phones-internal-storage)

I have the  HTC Status, and love it!  But lately I'm getting "Internal memory low" messages when I try to open or download something in my messages.   It tells me to go to the "settings" tab and make space.  I don't have many Apps on it, the biggest I believe is the FB App-but it's the so called "FB Phone" so why am I still having issues?  I uninstall and delete data and try to move things to the sd-card and empty inboxes all the time and it just moves a few MB and leaves me alone.  It gets bad sometimes, where it won't let me even ope and read a text even if there aren't any pics to load.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The sdcard is not included with internal memory. What it is actually complaining about is the location where the data and apps are stored (/data & /data/data) and could also include the cache (/cache). I have been saying for a while that more space needs to be allocated for these locations.

I have to go through and remove some apps some times, and even go to apps like Google+ and "clear data". Google+ is actually a good example of a data hog. I had to clear it today. Google+ was using 42MB of storage.

The best thing that I can suggest is to clear the data on apps that are "hogs" or remove apps that you don't use.