# An app that can give a clear overview of what exactly is eating up my phone space?

Tags: storage, sony-xperia-active

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/what-can-i-do-to-manage-my-phones-internal-storage)

I'm curious to know how my 2GB memory card could fill up so quickly as well as my internal phone memory. I already cleared up all SMS, taken pictures, taken videos that I can find. But it only changed to mere megabytes of space. I have the Xperia Active and I'm using the Sony Bridge for Mac. From there, it only says that the rest of the space is being occupied by "Others". No specific definition about what those might be.

On Windows, I use an app like http://windirstat.info/ to give myself an easily understandable overview of what's taking up the biggest space, etc. It would be appreciated if there's something like that for the Android or even just a simpler solution.

I just want to look at more detailed statistics as opposed to the one the Sony Bridge is giving me (see below).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T46FY.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Disk Usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) app. It draws nice graphical diagram with directories and files proportional to their size (similar to WinDir Stat).