# Motorola Triumph - how to decrease internal memory (clear log files)

Tags: internal-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/what-can-i-do-to-manage-my-phones-internal-storage)
>   [Something is secretly eating up my tablet memory and I need help finding it](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27127/something-is-secretly-eating-up-my-tablet-memory-and-i-need-help-finding-it)

I am wondering if there is a way, without root, to analyze the details of the internal memory on a Motorola Triumph and clear some extraneous (if they exist) log files. Many thanks in advance.