# My space used and free space doesn't add up

Tags: nexus-7, storage

See pic - the numbers don't add up!

[image: free space]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

This is a 16GB Nexus 7
The listed items only add up to a little over 9GB. So 4GB worth of files are missing.

How can I find those missing files?

Comment: You mean, your Nexus 7 is 16GB but appears only 13.2GB?

Comment: Any reasons for the downvotes?

Comment: @eldarerathis I see. Just saw the screenshot saying 13GB and him saying it's the 16GB version I immediately assumed that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @RichardBorcsik, the question is much clearer now.

Comment: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the displayed detailed would be **complete**, you'd be correct: 1.28G + 7.28G + 200K + 282M + 762M = 9.6 GB total space -- while the summary says 13.24G. Explanation is easy: The details list is *not* complete. It e.g. misses Cache, temporary files, log files, tombstones, and probably some more.

Where to find those? In the file system, and for completeness this requires root. For some more details, please take a look at corresponding questions by following the tags [internal-memory](/questions/tagged/internal-memory) and [storage](/questions/tagged/storage). A good source to start with is the question [Something is secretly eating up my tablet memory and I need help finding it](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27127/).

Comment: Thanks for that, will find a way of finding those files.

Comment: The linked article should get you started -- most needed details are covered there. Feel free to let us know where the gross of those ~3.6 GB were located. Btw: The screenshot information looks a bit misleading to me: "Apps (app data & media content)" could be interpreted to mean the data only, excluding the `.apk` files. So in case you cannot get together the missing space otherwise, consider to check that as well. Oh, and if you use App2SD, it might also be the "decoded `.apk` files" on internal storage...