# Missing storage on Tesco Hudl 2

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I have a Tesco Hudl 2 running Android 4.4.2. I have 9GB of total storage. But little free, despite not using much.

It shows a few GB in-use and 0.5GB free. The usage bar shows 80% available, but the table shows 581MB available. I used to have many apps installed, now there are fewer apps, and no room for more.

```
Total space 9.12GB
    Avalable 581MB
    Apps 1.58GB
    Pictures 12.46MB
    Audio 496kb, 
    Downloads 35.61MB, 
    Cached data 59.51MB
    Misc 113MB
```

That is less than 2GB in-use, and 9GB - 2GB = 7GB ≠ 0.5GB

I have no idea what has happened to the rest of the memory. Can you tell me how to fix, or diagnose?

Note: I have read [insufficient-memory](/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory) wiki.

---

It has 16GB of internal storage, and according to various websites I should only see about 9GB of this. The storage tool shows about 9GB of total storage.

As requested, I ran Diskinfo & DiskUsage. DiskUsage shows System data of 6782 MiB, this appears to be the problem, but what is system data, and why so much?

Diskinfo:

```
--------------------------
 Internal Storage (MMC)
--------------------------
 * Cache [mmcblk0p11] (/cache) [ext4]
   Used: 87.6 MB, Free: 1.4 GB, Total space: 1.5 GB
 * System [mmcblk0p13] (/system) [ext4]
   Used: 1.3 GB, Free: 761 MB, Total space: 2 GB
 * Data [mmcblk0p15] (/data) [ext4]
   Used: 8.8 GB, Free: 582 MB, Total space: 9.4 GB
--------------------------
 SD Card
--------------------------
 * SD card [mmcblk1p1] (/mnt/media_rw/sdcard1, /storage/sdcard1) [vfat]
   Used: 253 MB, Free: 29.5 GB, Total space: 29.7 GB
--------------------------
 Memory
--------------------------
 * RAM
   Used: 1018 MB, Free: 862 MB, Total space: 1.8 GB
```

DiskUsage:

```
Storage card: 9342 MiB
    apps: 1245 Mib
        …
    media: 734 Mib
        …
    System data: 6782 Mib
    Free space: 581 Mib
```

Comment: I can not workout how to do a screenshot, but it is saying that `/data` is `8.8GB used / 9.4GB`. It does no show detail like `du` it gives overview like `fdisk` + `df`. I can now see why the total is not 16GB (as advertised), but still have no idea what the 8.8GB is being used for.

Comment: Related: [My space used and free space doesn't add up](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33151/16575) / **[Something is secretly eating up internal memory and I need help finding it](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27127/16575)** / [3GB of internal storage is lost](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/113119/16575)

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same situation on my HUDL2.
8Gb of space lost in a black whole.
I did a web search and found one page where a user had the same problem. They had eventually rooted their HUDL2 and found this file "/data/IntelCPHS.log" taking up the missing space.
It's in the /data directory so it's protected and all I can do is list the size with a terminal emulator. It also doesn't show up in disk utilities because of the protected directory it is in.
I did a "ls -l /data/IntelCPHS.log" and found it was taking up nearly 8Gb.
Without rooting all I could do was a factory reset to remove it.
The only thing I've found that causes the file to grow is the All4 app. If I don't view anything with that the IntelCPHS.log stays nice and small.
So not a solution but maybe a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually fixed it by performing a system reset. So all data lost. Except what I copied off onto other devices.