# What are these dumpstate logs?

Tags: cyanogenmod, internal-storage, logging, cellular-radio

So, these files were filling up my `/data/logs` directory, causing me to run out of storage space rapidly.

What are they, why are there so many and how can I stop them clogging my storage?

[image: dumpstate log file name]
<sup>Screenshot (click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Liams related previous question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48277/where-has-all-my-storage-space-gone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I googled the file name and found this post on XDA:

> i'm still having the storage is running out error from 3.8. I found
>   out it was caused by the signal lost issue because inside the log
>   folder located in data folder, it will generate many dumpstate ril
>   reset by........xxx..once my signal is lost. so, i'm wondering what's
>   the best worldwide modem for 3.8 or lates nightly that won't cause
>   signal lost thus my phone won't generate the dumpstate ril reset error
>   and indirectly generating many dumpstate ril reset. I'm using dxlpa
>   modem.

Looks like your phone might be affected by a bug in CM. I would switch ROM and see if it goes away, if not, you could try an app like [GetRIL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sibbor.getril&hl=en) to find out what Radio Interface Layer you are using, and if there is another you can use that might help you not lose connection over and over.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is you have enabled the dumpstate in your mobile, please enter the keystring *#9900# and press SEND.
Will be open a new screen with some options, verify if SILENT LOG is OFF and DEBUG LEVEL is DISABLE/LOW.
This capabilities are used by developers to verify fails and debug application running in the device, as user you will never use it.

Answer (score -3):

Dial `*#9900#`, and delete all your log and dump files.

Note: Only works on Samsung.

Comment: That doesn't explain what they are?