# Why is my Nexus 7 taking up so much memory?

Tags: internal-storage, nexus-7, insufficient-memory

I had 2.2GB free on my Nexus 7's internal storage, then I decided to download a game that took up 1.55GB. Halfway through the download, it tells me that I have have insufficient memory and it stops the download. I then have around 500MB of storage left, and the app is no where in sight and I don't know how to clear up my memory. I decided to factory restore my tablet and afterwords I have 800MB of internal storage (it should have been around 500MB, but I didn't install some apps I had before). Does anyone know how I could get it back to 2.2GB? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Lots of useful information here: [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2065)

Comment: And here: [Something is secretly eating up my Acer Iconia A500 internal memory and I need help finding it](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27127/16575). Might prove helpful if you [edit] your question and include details on what storage we're talking about. The `insufficient-memory` error is only triggered for internal storage (usually when it falls below 25 MB), where playstore downloads usually go to (`/data/local`) but that would have been freed by a factory-reset. So how much space is avail/used/free on which storage (internal/SD/??)?