# Need a file explorer that supports root as well as showing the folder size

Tags: applications, file-management

There seems to be a serious dearth of quality apps on Android. I'm having memory issues in my Xperia L phone and I'm trying to determine the root cause. (No it's not the Album memory leak issue - I've already fixed that). There is a folder that's taking up a horrendous amount of space for some reason and I need to locate which one it is.

So my requirements are:

- A file explorer so i can check out different folders
- which supports root access so I can check out all folders
- which shows the folder size
- which allows me to sort folders by their sizes

So far I tried File Commander since it was so highly recommended. Weird that it doesn't support root.

Then i tried a couple of more file explorers each of which had 1-2 of the above features but doesn't have the others.

I also come across one file explorers that did have all these features but almost everything was locked up for "pro access".

Is there any File Explorer that supports all these functions? (IMO these are all basic features but maybe I got spoiled by Windows).

Comment: Related: [Something is secretly eating up my tablet memory and I need help finding it](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27127/16575)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app [Disk Usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) is not quite a file explorer, but it's ideal for seeing where your device's storage is used. It shows a hierarchical view of directories by how much storage they take up. You can use it without root to show your external storage, or with root to examine the internal filesystem and apps' private data.