# Cleaning up Samsung S2 memory

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, insufficient-memory

When I use the application manager, I see that 1.8GB are occupied out of 2GB available. This of course causes issues when installing apps and brings up a warning notifications that some system services may malfunction. However, if I sum the memory taken by my apps, I come up at 1GB, and many of these apps have been moved to the SD card.

I've tried to use Clean Master to free space, but without much success.

So I want to cleanup files manually. What partitions on the phone's system are the ones in the 2GB space? Is it the root partition?

Comment: You might wish to check: [Something is secretly eating up my Acer Iconia A500 internal memory and I need help finding it](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27127/16575) – and, of course, the [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/storage/sdcard/android` is probably where all the data is.  You can manually delete files out of there, but I would recommend using the application SD Card Maid.  I say that just because it has a lot of functions to clean up data from apps that are no longer installed.

Comment: SDCard has nothing to do with the "insufficient memory"/"insufficient storage" error (see the tag-wiki). More likely culprits are tombstones and `/data/local`. *SDMaid* is a good pointer, though – as it doesn't only care for the external SDCard. But for pretty much everything else, it needs root…

Comment: SD Maid is perfect! Down from 1.8G to 1.2G!

Comment: `/storage/sdcard` normally points to the internal storage partition of Android storage (the 2GB of his 8GB ROM).  That's where apps store external data, such as downloaded content and temp files (for example, com.amazon.venezia [Amazon App Store] stores all of its temporary apk downloads and partial downloads there).  But yes, the root `/data` folder is another huge culprit.  I didn't mention it explicitly because it needs root to access.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to clean your log files? Probably that's the problem.

If your phone is rooted, you can delete all files in the `/data/log` folder. If not, and you have a stock ROM, just enter `*#9900#` into your dialer to access SysDump and click on **Delete dumpstate/logcat**

Comment: Yes, I removed log files with SD Maid. Maybe that was indeed the culprit. If so, is there a way to prevent them from accumulating again?