# nexus 5x fills up storage with system crap

Tags: internal-storage, nexus-5x

My Nexus 5x is filling up its system storage space with data (location is upper /sdcard).

In the screenshot you can see the 3.25GB of data in other section.

Has anyone had this issue before? How do we clean it up and what is this data?

[image: Screenshot of internal storage]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Something is secretly eating up my Acer Iconia A500 internal memory and I need help finding it](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27127/something-is-secretly-eating-up-my-acer-iconia-a500-internal-memory-and-i-need-h)

Answer (score 3):

If you click on the 'Other' section (or the 'Explore' option at the bottom of the screen) it will allow you to browse the files/folders and delete any that you do not need.

The 'other' data is actually just files on your device which it does not know how to categorise e.g. downloaded files, files that are used by apps (which are stored outside of the `/Android/data` folder).

Note: If you randomly delete files/folders then some apps may need to re-downloade/re-create them in order to function correctly. If you're not sure what a file is it's probably best to leave it, just in case.