# Android 4.4.2 on Sumsung S4 has 100MB free from 5.18GB , what is using all the space

Tags: internal-storage

I cannot install disk-usage as i have no space.
Ive tried deleting stuff, removing apps...etc
but am only ambe to get back small amount.
Something is using up an enormous amount of disk-space.
What is it?
how do list hidden files etc.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you already consulted our [internal-storage tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/internal-storage/info)? It e.g. points to [Something is secretly eating up my tablet memory and I need help finding it](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27127/16575) which sounds quite similar. And there are more of the kind in [that tag's most frequent questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-storage?sort=frequent).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access via adb, you can navigate to the sdcard and run "du -sh *" or from the computer ' adb shell "du -sh *" ' and see the output of how large the folders are.  Likely Android is going to be big. You need to be selective about what you delete from the Android folder if that's the route you need to take.

If you can't look at things using adb:
Try clearing cache of apps that build up a lot of space such as youtube and google translate. Also, and if this doesn't free things up enough to install disk usage, look inside the Android folder of the sdcard.  There are two subfolders here to look at, on is data and the other is obb.  Games that take up a lot of space are often in obb; deleting here will screw up your game and you may have to reinstall entirely in order to get this data back, but it one way of clearing a big files in your scenario.  Cached data that really builds up goes in the data folder; look for youtube in case it wasn't cleared when you went to settings.  In fact a lot of Google apps keep ridiculous amounts of history which can eat up space.  Its best to try to clean it in settings>apps opposed to manually deleting it unless you feel you know your way around the files you're looking at.  Clearing files in Data, or clearing data via settings, will reset apps as if they were just installed which isn't convenient.

There is also sometimes a "clear cache" function in the menu to format the sdcards which can free up space without screwing things too bad however I haven't tried it on that device and only used it once on a different device.  You want to be careful you don't format a card in the process while in this menu.