# Can I move apps to internal USB storage?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, internal-storage

I have a Samsung Galaxy S. I am getting a "Low on space - Internal phone storage is getting low" error.

When I go to Manage Applications it shows the internal memory as 1.9GB used, 6.0 MB Free.
When I click "On SD Card" it shows "USB Storage 681 MB Used, 13 GB Free".
There is no external SD card in the device.

When I select an app and click "Move to SD Card" it just returns the following error:

Failed to move application. Not enough memory.

Is there any way I can move the apps to the internal USB memory?

---

Update: I've reset the phone to factory settings so no longer get the error about space getting low and internal storage is almost empty.
I've installed a couple of apps and still get the same error when I try migrate them to USB storage.

Comment: Have you tried using a third party application such as App2SD? Although you don't explicitly have an SD card (as you stated), it may allow you to solve your problem.

Comment: Before doing a factory reset (you already did, but maybe this is useful for "next time"), you might also want to check [Something is secretly eating up my tablet memory and I need help finding it](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27127/something-is-secretly-eating-up-my-tablet-memory-and-i-need-help-finding-it/) and [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/what-can-i-do-to-manage-my-phones-internal-storage)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to clean up your internal memory first before you can do anything.  There's three ways I can suggest to free some up:

1. Clean out your app caches to free up space (browsers and maps are usually the worst offenders): you can use an app like SD Maid (it's tiny, you should be able to install it) or by going into the application management section (`Settings->Applications->Manage Applications->All`, then click on an app name) and manually clearing out app data for hogs like Google Maps and the like using the `Clear cache` button (note: don't clear the app data! just the cache).
2. Uninstall some apps, then reinstall them after you've moved other apps to the SD card.
3. Root your phone and uninstall bloatware / system apps you don't use with an app like Titanium Backup (make sure you back up the apps first in case you need them later).  **Note:** this will keep your phone from being able to install carrier Android updates in the future.

Android is usually pretty good about auto-installing apps to non-system storage when possible.  Does your version have an option to prefer installing to SD set?

Comment: Thanks Logos. All good advice but see my update above. It doesn't seem to be related to the internal memory being full. I'm on stock and haven't found an option to auto install to SD.