# insufficient storage error while updating installed apps

Tags: internal-storage, installation, insufficient-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do to manage my phone’s internal storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/what-can-i-do-to-manage-my-phones-internal-storage)

I recently purchased a new Android mobile (Samsung Galaxy Y duos), running on Android 2.3.6. It have 8 GB microSD as external memory.

I installed quite a few application and unfortunately now I'm facing memory issue. While updating Facebook app (around 13 MB) or installing any other app with 10mb+ memory requirement, I got error message `Insufficient storage`.

I checked available storage, which is as follow:

```
SD card
Total space: 7.39 GB
Available space: 6.90 GB

System storage
Available space: 22.47 MB
```

There is lot of space on SD Card but yes system space is low. What is the efficient tricks/best practices to make sure system utilize more SD Card storage and less system storage so that I can install few more apps.

Is there any way to shift few installed apps from system storage to SD Card storage, un-installing and installing is also acceptable for few apps.

Answer (score 2):

**Why?**

You said: `System storage Available space: 22.47 MB` And Facebook app size is around 13MB. So why doesn't it update? It's because NOT ALL of the system storage is available for your Apps. Some space is reserved by Android. So unfortunately, you can't install Apps in that space.

About the space in SD card,

a. Facebook App is phone memory only app (Annoying!)

b. Mostly, your apps will be first downloaded to phone memory and then you can move them to SD card. So even if the app is movable to SD card, you will need phone memory to first install it!

**Solution:**

Now the solutions. Try these steps:

1) Move all apps (that can be moved) to SD card. You can do it from Settings or use [App2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd&hl=en) for the same.

2) Clear cache. Again I would suggest to use App2SD for the same. This should free up good amount of space.

3) Uninstall apps that you don't need anymore.

Another suggestion I have is to install a custom ROM that takes less space on your phone.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the latest Facebook application crosses the threshold of your system storage. This can be solved by either uninstalling some of the installed apps to allot more space, or by [rooting your phone](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1534983) and using [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD).

EDIT: Also, see [App2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd&hl=en) for moving some of your apps to the SD card. And if you choose to root your phone instead and use [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD), you'll have the option of uninstall pre-installed "bloatware" apps that you don't necessarily use but came with the phone.