# Insufficient memory error in google playstore, even though I have enough space

Tags: google-play-store, insufficient-memory

Recently I changed my sd card from 2GB to 8GB and now I can neither download nor update any apps from the Google Playstore. It shows "Insufficient space on device", even though internal 1.5gb & external 6gb is available. I tried clearing cache for apps, I also deleted some to restore space, but no use.

Can anyone please suggest what to do? This may be a duplicate question, none of the solutions worked for me. My phone is not rooted.

Comment: Gautami: You've already found the right tag for your question (which indeed is one of our most-frequently-asked). Have you checked with [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)? I'm pretty sure that will get you on the right tracks. Once done, please return and either answer your own question (if solved), put a comment pointing to the question holding your solution (again, if solved) – or [edit] your question to let us know what you've tried and where you're stuck. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Izzy! I'm expecting you here ;) I knew you would come. Looks like the girl who asked the question forgot that she asked a question ;)

Comment: Since my current reputation in android.stackexchange is not expressive as "10", I cannot post a good answer. But I can share this link so you can give it a try: http://www.itworld.com/article/2833377/insufficient-storage-available-is-one-of-android-s-greatest-annoyances-here-s-how-to-fix-it.html?page=3

Comment: possible duplicate of [“Insufficient storage available”. Ok, but where?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55098/insufficient-storage-available-ok-but-where)

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have enough space. Android installs apps to your internal SDcard, not your external. Going from 2 to 8 gigs is irrelevant when installing apps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to move your already installed applications to your external SD card?

You can do it in application settings, after a click on an application in the list.

There must have a button "move to SD card" or something similar. Note that  not all the apps can be moved to the external SD card this way.

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend using your computer to transfer all files and folders from the old SD card to the new one. This ensures a smooth SD card upgrade.

As for the space issue; the amount of your external memory doesn't resolve issues related to the internal memory. Only internal storage is used for apps installed on the majority of devices (it depends on the version of Android that is installed).