# Really know what is using internal storage

Tags: applications, internal-storage, app2sd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do to manage my phone’s internal storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/what-can-i-do-to-manage-my-phones-internal-storage)

I am constantly running into the "Low Space" warning so I would like to know what is really consuming the phone's internal storage.

I've checked and removed app after app, moved them to the SD card and done everything else I can think of but can't seem to figure out what is really consuming the phone's internal storage.

I can see the storage used per app but it seems like this not entirely correct numbers or something is not attached to an app and hence invisible to this app list.

So, is there a way to see what is really consuming the storage?

Comment: In a way it is, thanks for pointing out to me.

Answer (score 2):

[Disk Usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en) provides a way to find files and directories which consume a lot of space on phone and SD card

Comment: I've tried a number of "Disk Usage" apps and maybe it's just me but none of them are really helping me. It seems however like the "Contact Storage" is rather large and it might also be so that it is growing even if I am not modifying any of my contacts.

Comment: What does Disk Usage say, and what is your total phone capacity?

Answer (score -1):

You likely have a memory leak in one of your apps, Android 2.3 is prone to this type of an issue but newer versions are less likely to have this issue. A "Hard Reset" of your phone might be an ok temporary fix, but if it doesn't work and the Disk Usage doesn't tell you anything then i recommend finding a good app killer program.

Comment: You seem to be confusing internal storage with RAM -- if the phone is running out of space, app killer program won't be of much use.

Comment: I agree, it's not a RAM issue, inte Internal Phone storage. Thanks anyway