# View internal Storage use

Tags: internal-storage

I'd like to view use the meager internal storage on my HTC Evo.  The phone is rooted, and I have used Link2SD to move apps to the SD card.  I am also using DiskUsage by Ivan Voyosluk to monitor use of storage.  The DiskUsage app, however, does not seem to make a clear distinction between internal storage and external.  It appears it may be calculating the total by following the symlinks onto the SD card.  I'd like to know how much internal storage is actually being consumed by my apps.  I am continuing to run into the problem of running out of my meager internal storage while there is a huge amount of unused space on on my SD card.

Answer (score 1):

Several helpful apps are mentioned in the answers to [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/2065/16575) Guess the question and its answers would be useful/interesting to you anyhow.

Apart from that, there are also our useful command line utilities, which you can execute in a terminal (either via `adb shell`, or using a terminal app):

- `df`: stands for "disk free", but also shows the used space. Is not interested in files or symlinks, just operates on the entire partition. So this should list you up how much space is used/free on each storage.
- `du`: a close relative, "disk used". Is not interested in "divisions" such as partitions or directories by default (that can be dealt with via parameters), but checks "anything below". It doesn't follow symlinks, which might prove useful to you – as will the parameter `-s` (summary). Without that parameter, each directory would be listed up with the space consumed; with `-s` only a summary of all space used below the current location will be printed.

You will find several other useful commands in our [command-line tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/command-line/info). For your low memory, you also might want to visit our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info).