# KitKat - How to identify the REAL size of apps (app + datas + ...) to be able to install other ones

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, settings, installation, insufficient-memory

I had an iPhone for 4 years and I now have a Samsung Galaxy S5 running KitKat 4.4.2.
I've started the migration from the one to the other downloading my prefered apps.
I've just downloaded 40 little standard apps, half of the work, and my S5 already tells me that it cannot donwload any more apps from the Playstore, not enough space on the phone. What ??? But... I still have gigs of space... and I already moved out all possible apps from internal memory.

I've seen that I could bypass this by rooting the phone, but I can't deal with that. That's not a solution.

So I've started to search which are tha apps that take the more space.

On the iPhone, when I wanted to know the exact size that an app, I could see this onto the settings or into iTunes, giving the size of the app + its datas.

On KitKat, I don't see this information anywhere. As an example, I have "Maps with Me" installed, from which I have donwloaded around 1 gig of maps. It should be the one and largest app I have. But the best I can see about its space see is into the Application settings panel the following informations :

**Total :** 60,41 Mo
**Application :** 5,11 Mo
**Stock on phone app :** 55,09 Mo
**Datas :** 116 Ko
**Stock on phone datas :** 96,00 Ko
**Cache :** 64,00 Ko

Where are my gig of maps ? How can I sort my apps by their real space usage ?
And more, how can I install more than 40 littles apps on such a phone ? That seems incredible... There must be a standard way of doing that ?

**EDIT 1**

Clean Master tells me that "Maps With Me" is 656 Mb large. Well, OK, but isn't the default marvelous system able to do that ? Because I don't want such apps on my phone, just to do what the basic OS should do and bore me with other functionalities I don't want.

Clean Master also tells me that I have 64 apps occupying 2,5 Gb.
And that My free system space is 120,32 Mb.
After a clean with this app...
I only have my phone since 1 week, and I've nearly done nothing yet with it.

FYI, I've made a factory reset at the first use, and deleted any possible unwanted apps.

Comment: I've just added the 'insufficient-memory' tag to your question. You might wish to check [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for some first aid, especially follow the link to [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2065/16575)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are finding trouble to sort apps according to their size,name,date etc with the stock App manager. So I recommend you to install third-party app like Clean Master which does all the things you need. It is a small application so hopefully it won't give any *no space* error.

Comment: CleanMaster tells me that Maps With me is 656 Mb large. Well, ok, isn't the default system able to do that ?? I don't want such apps on my phone. It also tells me that I have 64 apps occupying 2,5 Gb. And that My free system space is 120,32 Mb. I only have my phone since 1 week, and nearly done nothing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are several things you can do to solve this problem (or, at least, to understand WHERE it is). 
The simplest I can think of are: 
1) Go to Settings -> Storage and see how the space is being used. Chances are you have one or more apps that use to download a lot of contents so you should find that the major part of your storage is occupied by "Miscellaneous" files. In this case you just have to tap on the related voice and you'll see a list of app and their data; 
2) Reboot your device into recovery mode and clear cache; 
3) Long press on Play Store -> Settings and clear its cache;

The last two ideas come from the fact that sometime Play Store and similar apps (Settings app too) give problems messages only because the cache is full of data (most of which is merely made up by useless things)... 
Just try and tell me if one of these three things works ;)

Comment: `/cache` usually resides on a separate partition, and thus shouldn't have to do with it (though I agree clearing cache doesn't hurt and often solves "strange errors"). But resetting the Playstore app definitely hasn't to do with this IMHO.

Comment: Didn't meant to say "reset play store". I just wanted to say "clear its cache" xD

Comment: You know you always can [edit] your post to fix that up? ;) Still: If there's not enough space left on internal storage, that won't help anyhow. Oliver needs to get the storage of his device straight.

Comment: Then he needs to check the first point I've written :P

Comment: Still he said that he has GBs of free space so I don't think he needs it xD
BTW he asked multiple things and I tried to answer to each of them. If he's going to give us more details then we'll help him further. Till then I think I covered the entire question :)

Comment: Users are often not aware about what the "insufficient storage" error refers to. 'Even with terrabytes free on SD, it would still be thrown when internal storage gets low. Hence my hint to the tag-wiki. // Thanks for updating your answer!

Comment: I accidentally deleted my last comment. BTW thank you to letting me know that I wrote something totally different from what I was thinking to write (paranormal cerebral activity xD). Guess we have to wait for his news now

Comment: 1) I've answered you for this into my edit1. 2) Nope, I've never done such a crazy thing with my iPhone in 4 years of use, I would prefer send my new S5 to trash if I have to, really have to do this on a phone just after a week of no use. There should be any other way of getting out of there. 3) No effect

Comment: @Izzy:It's just the phone out of the box, without any SD card added.

Comment: @Izzy:OK, I've read the tagged questions/answers and the thing that I have understood is that when you buy an 16 Gig Android phone, in fact you only buy a 1, perhaps 2 gig one to put apps and their stuffs. So if you don't take photos, or look at videaos or such things, you just have 6-10 Gig useless, here for nothing. That cannot be the answer, there would be nothing smart in such a phone... I can't believe that. In fact I think it would be just stupid to make an OS like this, so I may have had a bad understanding of what I've read. Is it ?

Comment: @Oliver not exactly. For one, that out of the 16 GB are max 9 GB avail to the user is manufacturer specific (Android system doesn't need that much space reserved). Secondly, matching the remaining space is up to the manufacturer again (internal storage versus internal SD). Third, there's always App2SD – which unfortunately some manufacturers prefer to block again. You cannot blame the OS for what's the manufacturers fault.

Comment: @Izzy:That's not correct. Talking about two writable and storage places, the fact that an app is allowed to be moved or not, the fact that datas have to be stored here and not there, the fact that almost any manufacturer has this nearly standard 1-2/8 gig free inner partition, the fact that a widget may not be ran from the internal solded memory component, or the fact that a said mature OS is not able or do not want to show a real app size for some reason, is not a manufacturer logic but the OS one. And plus, a manufacturer cannot build a phone that goes counter the OS way of working.

Comment: Again: go into Settings -> Storage and there is everything you'd like to know. And this is a service given to you by the OS, not by some third party apps (like Clean Master). Just go there and analyze which app is using more storage. And, BTW, cleaning cash is not (even using a lot of fantasy) comparable to a hard reset. You don't have to do paranormal things: just press two buttons, enter the stock recovery (you DON'T have to root your phone) and clean cache. Also keep in mind that we're trying to help you: if you know everything then don't ask...

Comment: @LeonGuerrero:As explained into the question, I don't see the downloaded maps size into the Settings -> Storage page. So I can't do any real analysis about apps occupation. And for sure, I don't know everything, but I'm suprised, from my experience, about how simple things seems to be so complicated (hoping not impossible) on a such a known OS from a known company.

Comment: @LeonGuerrero:Why do you say "if you know everything then don't ask" ? Where in my asking did you feel I was knowing everything ?

Comment: I've rebooted my device into recovery mode and cleared cache. Near no effect. I have now 90 MB free as stated by Cache Cleaner. So I still can't install the second half of my 80 apps I used to use. Even GoogleMaps crashes new at launch because of low space (if I remove some little MB, it runs fine).

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case of WhatsApp, I found that there is a directory under which all its media, etc., are stored.
I then used Total Commander to obtain the total size of that directory.
I expect it to represent very well the total storage size related to WhatsApp (though I have no references to back this up).
See related question [How to compute all space taken up by an app and its associated files](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/188214/how-to-compute-all-space-taken-up-by-an-app-and-its-associated-files).

For a generic app, if

1. it "encapsulates" all its related files (except perhaps for a little amount of information related to system/configuration) under a given directory, and
2. one can identify such directory,

you could use Total Commander or a similar app, as I did for WhatsApp.

If the app spreads files of significant size across the filesystem, I wouldn't know...