# Significance of Internal SD Card in Micromax phone

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, android-versions, internal-sd

I have brought the Micromax A106 phone that has 8GB ROM. When I see the internals of the phone, the internal memory of the phone is partitioned in two ways - 0.98 GB as Phone Memory while 5.85 GB as Internal SD Card Memory.

All the apps, phone contacts etc are getting stored in Phone Memory (0.98 GB partitioned) due to which the phone memory is getting a low space and whenever I install any app from Play Store, I'm getting "Error: Cannot install due to insufficient space"

However, when I installed the SD Card, I was able to install/move the apps to External SD partition slot since the phone contains Android 4.4 Kitkat operating system.

How can I make use of the Internal SD Card Memory so that my Phone memory is not getting full?

Comment: Sounds like you're asking [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2065/16575) (for a starter, there's always our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) to guide you)

Comment: Apps are supposed to be installed in 5.85 Gb space actually. I don't know why apps are being installed in 0.98 Gb space! Contact Micromax Mobile once.