# insufficient space on the device in my Micromax canvas 4 what to do

Tags: insufficient-memory

What to do ?
I can not install any application in my device? 
I have tried clearing cache of all the applications .

Comment: Start with reading our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info). this is a pretty frequent question, so it has been answered several times already. The tag-wiki sums it up.

Answer (score 0):

Your best chance is try and move as many apps as you can to External Storage such as SD Card. Remember, you can only move "Certain" apps to SD Card, and not all.

Also, check below link.
[What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/what-can-i-do-to-manage-my-phones-internal-storage)

You may be able to find useful tips which should help you mitigate the problem that your currently facing!