# Android Marshmallow internal storage problem

Tags: internal-storage, 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-e

I have a Moto E 2nd Gen running Android 6.0.  In the Storage & USB menu it shows that I have used up over 4 GB of space, but it shows I have used only 2.5 GB for apps and around 100 MB of other data.

What is causing the discrepancy? Even clearing the cache does not help.

[image]

I tried DiskUsage. This is ascreenshot of my internal storage.

[image]

It shows System Data as almost 4GB. Is this normal ?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what you're describing -- how do you know you've only used 2 GB?  In the meantime, see http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2065/1465

Comment: I have posted the screenshot as u told...

Comment: Thanks, that's much clearer.  I've re-opened the question.  Try the Disk Usage app mentioned in the link above, and see if it gives you any more info.

Comment: The `/system` partition occupying about 4GB is normal, as that is the Android OS. I'm not exactly sure about the storage discrepancy, though

Comment: I thought that Android OS already occupies 3GB of my 8GB internal storage.